# Como converter Date para inteiro em java?

Tags: java, data, conversão-de-tipo

Quando eu utilizo esse código:

```
Date data = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat formatador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");           
int dataAtual =  Integer.parseInt(formatador.format(data));
System.out.println(dataAtual);
```

Aparece esse erro:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "15/09/2017"
> at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
> ```

Acredito ser porque no formato Date existem as barras e elas não são diretamente convertidas para inteiro, mas não sei como fazer essa conversão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entendo que você deseja um formato diferente mas [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12592654/4551469) o parâmetro na criação do `SimpleDateFormat` não contém barras (consequentemente a "data gerada" também não); tenta criar assim:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatador = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
```

Comment: nossa, meu erro foi muito bobo ahahahah obrigada

Comment: que nada, erro é erro :P

Answer (score 2):

Talvez o que você deseje não é transformar em inteiro a data, mas pegar o seu valor em milissegundos? Se for esse o caso, você pode fazer da seguinte forma.

```
//Cria nova data
Date d = new Date();
//Printa o valor da data em millissegundos..
System.out.println(d.getTime());
```

Ou, Se voce realmente quer converter a 'data' em inteiro tipo 06/03/2017 para 06032017.. você pode fazer algo assim..

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(sdf.format(d)));
```

Espero que seja alguma dessas soluções que vc deseja.

Answer (score 0):

As datas em java são armazenadas internamente como o número de milisegundos desde 1/1/1970 por isso o resultado é maior do que o limite de armazenamento do tipo `int`, para resolver este problema você deve usar um Long. Uma solução seria a seguinte:

```
int i = (int) (new Date().getTime()/1000);
System.out.println("Integer : " + i);
System.out.println("Long : "+ new Date().getTime());
System.out.println("Long date : " + new Date(new Date().getTime()));
System.out.println("Int Date : " + new Date(((long)i)*1000L));
```

Créditos: [Convert current date as integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067697/convert-current-date-as-integer)

Outras referências:

[Conheça a nova API de datas do Java 8](http://blog.caelum.com.br/conheca-a-nova-api-de-datas-do-java-8/)

[Date (Java SE 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)

Comment: testei apenas o inteiro(que é o que eu quero) e aparece: 1505503917, mas eu preciso apenas do dia, mês e ano, nessa ordem, consigo retirar apenas isso?

Comment: Se sua intenção é manipular (somar/subtrair dias) isso não vai dar muito certo.

Comment: resolvi com as respostas abaixo. Obrigada!!!